# Is there any way to trace any compiler's template argument deduction?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am looking for way to get some trace log from compiler's logic when it is trying to deduce template argument types, whenever it successes or not. 
So for example, given then code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) foo(T&& t) -> decltype(t + t)
{
    return t + t;
}

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) foo(T&& t) -> decltype(t.size()) 
{
    return t.size();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(10) << '\n'
              << foo(std::vector<int>{1,2,3}) << '\n';
}
```

I'd love to receive something like:

```
foo(10)

candidate: decltype(auto) foo(T&& t) -> decltype(t * t): seems valid
candidate: decltype(auto) foo(T&& t) -> decltype(t.size()): wrong one
```

Compilers are pretty good at it already, for example with providing the ambiguous calls. E.g. if I called `foo(std::string("qwe"));` I'd get:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:23:31: error: call of overloaded 'foo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)' is ambiguous
         foo(std::string("qwe"));
                               ^

main.cpp:7:20: note: candidate: decltype ((t + t)) foo(T&&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; decltype ((t + t)) = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
     decltype(auto) foo(T&& t) -> decltype(t + t)
                    ^~~

main.cpp:13:20: note: candidate: decltype (t.size()) foo(T&&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; decltype (t.size()) = long unsigned int]
     decltype(auto) foo(T&& t) -> decltype(t.size())
                    ^~~
```

And, if this explicit feedback is not possible, maybe there is a way to get view of "semi-compiled" code, with all template deduction already done?

Does any of compilers have such feature? gcc, clang, mvsc?

#### Backround:

This example is quite easy and obvious, but I do experiment with `ranges::v3` library and struggle to understand why one specific case does work and why the other does not.
(Technically, `iterator_range<Handmade InputIterator>` piped with `view::take(3)` returns `void` instead of some fancy `range`, but is not matter of this question. I want to trace deduction on almost same line, but with `iterator_range<ContiguousIterator>` and see the difference.

Comment: I'm worried about the sheer number of messages such a feature would generate though.

Comment: You want to know **all** deduced ones, not only those related to some error?

Comment: @liliscent Yes, since my in problem is there is no error. Operations do compile, but return type is `void`, so I cannot use their result.

Comment: @Caninonos So do I, but I can pin my problem down to one line. One line which returns void instead of type that I expected. That's why I want to trace almost same line, but with type which returns proper type and see the difference (on which template deduction my type does not fit given internal concepts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Templight](https://github.com/mikael-s-persson/templight) is a clang-based tool for tracing the progress of template instantiations.  It has an interface similar to the gdb debugger, so you can focus in on a certain instantiation that's causing errors or not behaving as expected.  Or you can have it output a "profile" of the template instantiations, which would give an overview of all of them.

There's also a related tool [Templar](https://github.com/schulmar/Templar) which is apparently a graphical interface to Templight's debugger mode, though I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Nice, thanks :) I've +1 you and I'll accept it in few days, but for now I'll keep it open for now with hope for more answers